# How can i change the background color of datagridview headercell in code using C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to change the backcolor of a headercell in datagridview row .So how can I do that in code C#?

Also, how do I change font properties of the text named as value of the headercell like `headercell.value`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the properties window. Set EnableHeadersVisualStyles to false then make the changes to the font, cell color, alignment, etc in ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to change the backcolor using:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[index].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

I still don't know the answer to my second question.

Answer (score 0):

To change the font properties of a specified header cell you can try:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[index].HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 24, , FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
dataGridView1.Columns[index].HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 24, , FontStyle.Bold);
```